# Does Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancer supports gRPC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to figure out if Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancer that is attached to the GKE cluster when an ingress point is created supports grpc

so far, all I can find is this documents showing how to use envoy to expose a service

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-on-gke-using-envoy-proxy

but nothing that works with the ingress preconfigured on Google Cloud

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. You will need to enable [HTTP/2 support](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) in the HTTP Load balancer. Here are instructions on how to setup [HTTP/2 for load balancing with Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-http2) in GKE.

Comment: Are you sure that HTTP/2 is required for gRPC?

Comment: Yes gRPC makes use of HTTP/2 as the transport.

Comment: Making use of a feature is not the same as requiring it in order to function. Do you have a link that details the requirements for gRPC?

Comment: Sure check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC). Transport is not an optional thing :) . Read more technical details [here](https://blog.netsil.com/http-2-and-grpc-the-next-generation-of-microservices-interactions-aff4ffa6faed).

Comment: Kunal, I guess I will say it this way. gRPC supports HTTP/1.1. The gRPC-Web Spec supports both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

Comment: Thats true, but you need HTTP/2 utilize all the features of gRPC. Details at [The state of gRPC in the browser](https://grpc.io/blog/state-of-grpc-web/).

Comment: You missed my point. Your answer states: "You will need to enable HTTP/2 support". Please share a document that states this fact otherwise your answer is possibly wrong. I work with gRPC in Go, my code does not care if the server is HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2.

Comment: My answer is valid in GCP's context.